# Short Exact Sequence of a Hyperplane in the Projective Space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-geometry, exact-sequence, projective-schemes

Let $H$ be a hyperplane in $\mathbb P^n$ where $f:H\rightarrow \mathbb P^n$ is the closed immersion. Let $\mathcal F$ be a coherent subsheaf of $\mathcal E = \oplus\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(l)$.

There is a short exact sequence:
$$
0\rightarrow \mathcal F(d-1)\rightarrow\mathcal F(d)\rightarrow\mathcal F_H(d)\rightarrow 0
$$
The author also claims that if we select $H$ which does not meet any associate point of $\mathcal E/\mathcal F$, then $i_H:\mathcal F_H\rightarrow \mathcal E_H$ is injective.

My questions are:

1. How to define the short exact sequence? Is this sequence always exact for any $H$?
2. Why $i_H: \mathcal F_H\rightarrow \mathcal E_H$ is injective if $H$ contains no associated point of $\mathcal E/\mathcal F$?
3. If we regard $H = \mathbb P^{n-1}$, why $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^{n}}(l)|_H  = \mathcal O_{H}(l)$? (i.e.Why the pullback is the twist sheaf of $H=\mathbb P^{n-1}$)

This question is from the proof of Mumford's theorem. Following are the statement of the theorem and related part of the proof:
[image]
[image]

Another parts:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Voted to close for missing context. This is basically a PSQ, and you don't mention where you're reading this (despite an allusion to "the author"). Please consult [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and improve your question by making an [edit].

Comment: Thank you for point out. I will edit my question.

Comment: For q.1) For $H$ an hyperplane, you always have an exact sequence $0 \to O_X(-1) \to O_X \to O_H$ (Hartshorne, Algebraic Geometry, Prop 6.18). Then you tensor this sequence by $F$. Beware though that the tensor product is not exact in general, that's why the author argue with associated points etc... 
For qu.3) Denote $i:H\simeq \mathbb{P}^{n-1} \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ the closed immersion. You know that $i^*(O(1))$ is a line bundle on $H$, so it is of the form $O_H(k)$ for some interger $k$. You can compute $k$ by various method (for instance chern classes, intersection of divisors...).